# Java Syntax Analyzer

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

My Token Class

```
public class Token {
public enum TokenType {
RELATIONALOPERATOR("==|<>|<=|>=|>|<"), MULTIPLYINGOPERATOR("[*/]"), SIGNADDINGOP("[+-]"), LEFTPAREN(
    "\\("), RIGHTPAREN("\\)"), COMMA(","), PEROID("\\."), ASSIGNMENTOP("="), SEMICOLON(";"), WHILE(
        "while"), IF("if"), ELSE("else"), COMMENT("//"), PUBLIC("public"), PRIVATE("private"), PACKAGE(
            "package"), IMPORT("import"), ENUM("enum"), CONSTANT(
                "[0-9]*"), VARIABLE("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"), SKIP("[\\s+\\t]*"), INVALID(".*");

public final String pattern;

private TokenType(String pattern) {
    this.pattern = pattern;
}
}

public TokenType type;
public String data;

public Token(TokenType type, String data) {
  this.type = type;
  this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("[ %s, %s ]", type.name(), this.data);
}
}
```

My lexical analyzer class:

```
public static ArrayList<Token> lex(String input) {
// The tokens to return
ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();

StringBuffer tokenPatternsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for (TokenType tokenType : TokenType.values()) {
    // format everything to match |(?<EXAMPLE> [0-9]*)
    tokenPatternsBuffer.append(String.format("|(?<%s>%s)", tokenType.name(), tokenType.pattern));

}
Pattern tokenPatterns = Pattern.compile(tokenPatternsBuffer.substring(1));
//System.out.println(tokenPatternsBuffer.substring(1));

// Object that finds matches of pattern tokenPatterns
Matcher matcher = tokenPatterns.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    for (TokenType tk : TokenType.values()) {
    // don't want to grab spaces
    if (matcher.group(TokenType.SKIP.toString()) != null) {
        continue;
    }
    // grab anything that isn't a space and add TokenType to the
    // matcher group using .named() because the text matching
    // exactly is vital
    else if (matcher.group(tk.name()) != null) {
        tokens.add(new Token(tk, matcher.group(tk.name())));
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    }
}

return tokens;
}

static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
return new String(encoded);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String toDebugg = readFile("Test.java");
ArrayList<Token> myTokens = lex(toDebugg);
// System.out.println(toDebugg);
// for (Token tok : myTokens) {
// System.out.println(tok);
// }
}
```

I've narrowed down the issue to the `while(matcher.find())` loop. Inside the loop printing `matcher.group()` yields nothing. When I run the code in the above main method I receive 1 print of [PACKAGE, package] and then 40 prints of "[CONSTANT, ]" whereas the next token matched should be "[Variable, myLex]" (the package name) the file I've been testing my lexical analyzer on is called Test.java and it's contents are

```
package myLex;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }

}
```

I expect it to print something like [PUBLIC, public], [CLASS, class] ect... in the form [TYPENAMEHERE, actualRegexMatchHere] until it reads through the whole file. Thanks to Erwins advice special characters have now been escaped, but the issue persists.

Comment: Not an answer but your parser will need different tokens for `>=,<=,==,<,>,+,-,*,/,%` etc. Otherwise you have to scan everything twice. Don't lose information in lexical analysis.

Comment: You should escape the special characters in your tokens like the lparen, otherwise they are interpreted as regex special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Originally my regex was defined as
     `CONSTANT("[0-9]*"), VARIABLE("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"), SKIP("[\\s+\\t]*"), INVALID(".*");`

`[0-9]*` will match anything because of the star character. Replacing all * with + in the regex fixed the problem.